# Reverse iteraction in a tree-like Object

Tags: c#, tree, logic, iteration, reverse

I have an silly implementation of a tree and its iteration in a regular order.

Something like (the code is merely illustrative):

```
public IEnumerable<ReferenceNode<TItem, TKey>> AllBellow(ReferenceNode<TItem, TKey> node)
{
    if (/*some codition that tells me that i can return this*/)
    {
        yield return node;
    }
    else 
    {
        foreach (var child in node.Children)
        {
            foreach (var grandChild in AllBellow(child))
            {
                yield return grandChild;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Right, so how could I, starting from the root, reverse the iteration? I mean, instead of going **down** and from **left** to **right**, go **down** and **right** to the **left**...

If the question is not quite clear, please help me straighten it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood you just need to reverse children:

```
public IEnumerable<ReferenceNode<TItem, TKey>> AllBellow(ReferenceNode<TItem, TKey> node)
{
    if (/*some codition that tells me that i can return this*/)
    {
        yield return node;
    }
    else 
    {
        foreach (var child in node.Children.Reverse())
        {
            foreach (var grandChild in AllBellow(child))
            {
                yield return grandChild;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I`d rather not use linq as it may be too slow for my scenario

Comment: @NoProblemBabe: `yield return` is the founding stone of LINQ.

Comment: I am aware of it, the late iteration, concatenating all the iterations and all.

Comment: I did the reverse for inside of it